# application to see the cpu architecture in a figure

Tags: linux, memory, gui

I remember there was an application that showed, in the console, or in a simple picture, the memory architecture of the system: what caches were shared by which processors, etc. but I can't remember that command. Does any of you remember off the top of your head?

Comment: `hwloc`, that was it. Sorry. Maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: You should post it as an answer and then accept it when you can :) Good job finding the answer to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per 2 requests, I will answer my question explicitly, but I will not mark it as accepted. Sounds weird to me.

The answer I was looking for is `hwloc-info`, or, alternatively `lstopo -v --whole-system <optional-output-file>`, the `<optional-output-file>` may be any of the major image formats `ps`, `jpg`, etc,